# Klov Server throwing freemarker.core._TemplateModelException - Not able to generate/see any extent reports on Klov Server

Tags: automated-tests, extentreports

Successfully installed klov server on localhost:90 and mongodb 3.2 is running/listening on port 27017

After login to localhost:90 with klovadmin/password, command prompt for klov showing "Error executing FreeMarker template"

```
   2018-11-13 015:54:07.367 ERROR 10504 --- [ qtp19615804-36]
   freemarker.runtime                       : Error executing FreeMarker
   template

   freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: Java method
   "com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color.byStatus(String)" threw an
   exception when invoked on com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color object
   "com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color@1f29da2"; see cause exception in
   the Java stack trace.

   ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
           - Failed at: ${Color.byStatus(project.lastReport.s...  [in template "project.select.ftl" at line 46, column 117]
   ----
           at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:289) ~[freemarker-2.3.28.jar!/:2.3.28]
           at freemarker.ext.beans._MethodUtil.newInvocationTemplateModelException(_MethodUtil.java:252) ~[freemarker-2.3.28.jar!/:2.3.28]
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: This is because of mismatched versions of the API and server.  See http://extentreports.com/community/ here, at the very bottom you can download Klov 0.1.1 which will not give you this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was related to Klov-0.2.0, which is not currently supported for C# (only java at this time).

To run the server use Klov-0.1.1 which is available at http://extentreports.com/community/